# What is the difference between creating database role and application role?

Tags: sql-server

I want to have a role called ValidUsers.

My application will check if the user belongs to this group. If so then allow him to access the application.

Now when I right click roles under the database, I can see database role and application role. What is the difference between these and which fits into my use case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Application Roles are a mechanism where you allow a client application to connect the user via their own login (either Windows Authentication or SQL Server Authentication) - once the user has connected the application executes `sp_setapprole` to switch security context into the app role.

The app role would have appropriate permissions as needed in the database.  The user's login would only have `CONNECT` permission.

This prevents connections from seeing data in the database unless they know the password for the app role.

Take a look at the [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/authentication-access/application-roles?view=sql-server-ver15) for more details and examples.